# Setting up an array to save sounds in Android app

Tags: android, arrays, audio, save

Hi everyone I have been looking around for a while now and have been unable to find an answer to my question. I am new to Android Programming and have taken some but not much Java in College but have taken other languages so I understand concepts. I am asking how do I implement the array I created into my save function. I thought I knew how but just passing `saveasRing(0)` where my array contains the raw value but I receive a force close so that is why I am asking. Here is my code.

I am not asking for someone to write my code but to explain to me what to do... I want to learn, and hope I am just overlooking something but if not please lead me in the correct direction.
Thank you!

```
String[] name ={ "a1", "a", "b","c"}; //code shortened
int[] sounds = {R.raw.a1, R.raw.a };  //code shortened for ease of reading

public void function1(int id){  // when I change int to int[] Eclipse wants me 
                                // to change alot of things and then the app will 
                                // force close on start
  saveasRing(sounds);           // right here I have tried passing "0" instead 
                                // of sounds, a no go.

  Toast.makeText(this, "Saved as Ringtone", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
}//Closes Function 1  

//Save as Ringtone Coding for Function 3  
public boolean saveasRing(int ressound){  
  byte[] buffer=null;  
  InputStream fIn = getBaseContext().getResources().openRawResource(ressound);  
  int size=0;  

  try {  
    size = fIn.available();  
    buffer = new byte[size];  
    fIn.read(buffer);  
    fIn.close();  
  } 
  catch (IOException e) {  
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block  
    return false;  
  }  

  String path="/sdcard/media/audio/ringtones/";  
  String filename= name +".mp3";  

  boolean exists = (new File(path)).exists();  
  if (!exists){new File(path).mkdirs();  }  

  FileOutputStream save;  
  try {  
    save = new FileOutputStream(path+filename);  
    save.write(buffer);  
    save.flush();  
    save.close();  
  } 
  catch (FileNotFoundException e) {  
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block  
    return false;  
  } 
  catch (IOException e) {  
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block  
    return false;  
  }      

  sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE,
                Uri.parse("file://"+path+filename)));  

  File k = new File(path, filename);  
  ContentValues values = new ContentValues();  
  values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, k.getAbsolutePath());  
  values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, "dosequis");  
  values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/mp3");  
  values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, "Most Interesting Man ");  
  values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);  
  values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, false);  
  values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, false);  
  values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, false);  

  //Insert it into the database  
  this.getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(k.getAbsolutePath()), values);  

  return true;  
}
//Closes Save as Ringtone
```

Here is the Logcat of what happens when I long hit ringtone. The context menu comes up fine, just when I choose the type to save as I get a force close and these errors. Thank you for your time again.

Please let me know if there is a better way to format this.

```
 W/ResourceType(225):No package identifier when getting name for resource number 0x00000000

D/AndroidRuntime(225):Shutting down VM

W/dalvikvm(225): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)

E/AndroidRuntime(225):Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception

E/AndroidRuntime(225):android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0

E/AndroidRuntime(225):at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:891)

E/AndroidRuntime(225):at Android.content.res.Resources.openRawResource(Resources.java:816)

E/AndroidRuntime(225):at android.content.res.Resources.openRawResource(Resources.java:798)

E/AndroidRuntime(225):at tomcavell.app.DosEquisSoundboardActivity.saveasRing(DosEquisSoundboardActivity.java:270)

E/AndroidRuntime(225):at tomcavell.app.DosEquisSoundboardActivity.function1(DosEquisSoundboardActivity.java:253)

E/AndroidRuntime(225):at tomcavell.app.DosEquisSoundboardActivity.onContextItemSelected(DosEquisSoundboardActivity.java:245)

E/AndroidRuntime(225):at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2174)

E/AndroidRuntime(225):at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$ContextMenuCallback.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:2731)

E/AndroidRuntime(225):at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:139)

E/AndroidRuntime(225):at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:855)

E/AndroidRuntime(225):at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuDialogHelper.onClick(MenuDialogHelper.java:129)

E/AndroidRuntime(225):at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$AlertParams$3.onItemClick(AlertController.java:884)

E/AndroidRuntime(225):at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)

E/AndroidRuntime(225):at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3285)

E/AndroidRuntime(225):at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1640)

E/AndroidRuntime(225):at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)

E/AndroidRuntime(225):at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)

E/AndroidRuntime(225):at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)

E/AndroidRuntime(225):at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)

E/AndroidRuntime(225):at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

E/AndroidRuntime(225):at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)

E/AndroidRuntime(225):at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)

E/AndroidRuntime(225):at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)

E/AndroidRuntime(225):at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

I/dalvikvm(225): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3

I/dalvikvm(225): Wrote stack trace to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
```

Comment: You are going to need to include any exceptions you're getting under logcat for us to really know where the problem lies.  I see several issues regarding reading and writing IO streams that could lead to other problems, but why its force closing is not readily apparent.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to properly format your code, and use spaces to indent rather than tabs. (Hint: You can preview your post's formatting real-time just below the area where you're typing your question.) Formatting it properly makes it easier for people to read, improving your chances of getting an answer, and saves others from having to edit it for you. :) Thanks.

Comment: Thank you Ken, Like I said I am kind of new to Java and the way to format it. For now on I will make it look like it does now!  Thank you.

Comment: And  Chubbard I will do that now, I thought it was just a simple array problem. It only force closes when I try to save with passing 0 to the saveasRing function      saveasRing(0);     Otherwise the app does run correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I figured, out my problem. I had to set up the code with an int and then set that int as

```
j=sounds[i]; //(assuming j was the int declared)
```

Then pass the function saveasRing with i as in

```
saveasRing[i];
```

Thank you for looking and helping!